# An Applescript that batch-copies the Song tag to the Movement tag

Tags: itunes, applescript, music

I have a rather large iTunes library (~300GB) that is mainly classical music. I really like the Work and Movement format, but sadly it is not practical to manually update my metadata to the Work and Movement format. Almost all of the extisting song tags are in the following format:

```
Telemann - Concerto in E minor: I. Andante
II. Allegro
III. Largo
IV. Allegro
etc.
```

A script that could automate updating the tagging system would look like the following.

1. On all selected songs, copy the Song tag to the Movement tag
2. Delete the roman numeral, period and space from the front of the Movement tag. Or, on the format where the entire work name in included in the Song tag, delete that.

Any help or pointers for actually implementing this script would be very helpful. I have looked at and used [Doug's Work and Movement scripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/2016/08/a-couple-of-work-and-movement-scripts/), but they don't cover the matching process that would be needed to delete the roman numerals from the start.

**EDIT**

It has become apparent that many of the tags are not in the above format, but in a format like below:

```
Serenade for strings in C major, Op. 48 - I. Allegro
Serenade for strings in C major, Op. 48 - II. Adagio
Serenade for strings in C major, Op. 48 - III. Allegro moderato
etc.
```

OR in the same format as above except using arabic numerals in the place of the roman numerals.

The script should result in the "Movement" tags having the following outputs:

```
Allegro
Adagio
Allegro moderato
```

The idea is I would get the first part of this ("Serenade for strings in C major, Op. 48") and copy it to the "work" tag, which I have already implemented, then get the remaining text, remove the movement numbers, and assign it to the Movement tag. Any help on implementing a system that would do this would be appreciated.

Here is the script in its current form. It is based on Doug's Name to Work script.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set sel to selection of front browser window
    if sel is {} then
        try
            display dialog "Nothing is selected…" buttons {"Quit"} with icon 0
        end try
        return
    end if

    set c to (count of sel)
    set songName to (get name of item 1 of sel)


    set userOptions to display dialog "Edit for Work name and then click OK." default answer songName --prompt for work name

    repeat with i from 1 to c --set the movement numbers
        set thisTrack to item i of sel
        try
            set work of thisTrack to text returned of userOptions
            set movement number of thisTrack to i
            set movement count of thisTrack to c
            set movement of thisTrack to my delRomNum(name of thisTrack) -- copy movement text from song name and delete roman numerals
        end try
    end repeat


end tell

on delRomNum(t) -- the perl command search and delete any roman numeral (must be a word followed by the period and a space character)
    do shell script "/usr/bin/perl -pe 's/\\b[IVXLCDM]+\\b. //g' <<< " & quoted form of t
end delRomNum
```

Comment: @jackjr300 You might be able to help? Take this as a complement.

Comment: @kopischke You might be able to help too. Let me know if you can :) I'm pinging the "experts" at AppleScripting.

Comment: Please edit your "EDIT" and show the expected output you're looking to assign to the Movement tag from "_It has become apparent that many of the tags are not in the above format, but in a format like below:_" because the output you want is not obvious.

Comment: @user3439894 Done. Thanks for pointing out the unclarity (is that a word?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the roman numerals, you can use the `delRomNum()` handler from this script:

```
--- this text as an example.
set movementText to "Telemann - Concerto in E minor: I. Andante
II. Allegro
III. Largo
IV. Allegro
etc."

set movementText to my delRomNum(movementText) -- delete roman numerals


on delRomNum(t) -- the perl command search and delete any roman numeral (must be a word followed by the period and a space character)
    do shell script "/usr/bin/perl -pe 's/\\b[IVXLCDM]+\\b. //g' <<< " & quoted form of t
end delRomNum
```

The result of the script is

> ```
> "Telemann - Concerto in E minor: Andante
> Allegro
> Largo
> Allegro
> etc."
> ```

---

**Update:**

If I understood correctly :

From each line in a string, the command must delete the characters
   from the beginning of the line through the first occurrence of (a
   roman numeral or an arabic numeral) followed by the period and a
   space character, so use this handler:

```
-- call it, like this --> set movement of thisTrack to my delRomNum(name of thisTrack)
on delRomNum(t)
    (***  from  the contents of the 't' variable (the end of lines must be an Unix Line Endings), so the 'tr' command change the carriage returns (Mac Line Endings) to linefeed (Unix Line Endings)
    the 'perl' command delete the first character in each line through the first occurrence of a word  which contains (a roman numeral or a number) followed by the period and a space character ***)
    do shell script "tr '\\r' '\\n' <<< " & (quoted form of t) & " | /usr/bin/perl -pe 's/^.*?\\b[IVXLCDM0-9]+\\b. //g'"
end delRomNum
```

Example: the script pass this string to the handler as parameter

```
Serenade for strings in C major, Op. 48 - I. Allegro
Serenade for strings in C major, Op. 48 - II. Adagio
Serenade for strings in C major, Op. 48 - III. Allegro moderato
Serenade for strings in C major, Op. 48 - 4. Allegro  Molto Appassionato
Serenade for strings in C major, Op. 48 - 5. Adagio - Allegro Molto
Serenade for strings in C major, Op. 48 - 6. Allegro moderato
VII. Adagio - Allegro Non Troppo
8. Allegro Ma Non Tanto
9. Largo
Adagio
etc.
```

The handler returns:

```
Allegro
Adagio
Allegro moderato
Allegro  Molto Appassionato
Adagio - Allegro Molto
Allegro moderato
Adagio - Allegro Non Troppo
Allegro Ma Non Tanto
Largo
Adagio
etc.
```

Comment: This works really well, thanks so much. I really don't know what I am doing and actually added a section to the question and my current script, if you could take a look and give me any pointers then that would be extraordinarily useful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've figured this out myself. In the case that this is helpful to someone else, this is the complete script.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set sel to selection of front browser window
    if sel is {} then
        try
            display dialog "Nothing is selected…" buttons {"Quit"} with icon 0
        end try
        return
    end if

    set c to (count of sel)
    set songName to (get name of item 1 of sel)


    set workName to display dialog "Edit for Work name and then click OK." default answer songName --prompt for work name
    set movementLength to display dialog "Edit to everything except the movement name. Do not include the roman numeral if one is present. If an arabic numeral is present, include it." default answer songName --prompt for movement length


    repeat with i from 1 to c --set the movement numbers
        set thisTrack to item i of sel
        set songName to (get name of thisTrack)
        set work of thisTrack to text returned of workName
        set movement number of thisTrack to i
        set movement count of thisTrack to c
        set movement of thisTrack to my delRomNum(text ((length of text returned of movementLength) + 1) thru (length of songName) of songName as string) -- copy movement text from song name and delete roman numerals
    end repeat


end tell

on delRomNum(t) -- the perl command search and delete any roman numeral (must be a word followed by the period and a space character)
    do shell script "/usr/bin/perl -pe 's/\\b[IVXLCDM]+\\b. //g' <<< " & quoted form of t
end delRomNum
```

Comment: see my updated answer.